# Tangent vector cross product with binormal vector

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

If $\gamma$ is a curve in space with unit tangent, unit normal and binormal $T,N,B$ respectively, is it true that
\begin{equation}
T \times B =-N
\end{equation}
? I feel that this should be true by analogy with the canonical basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: How would you prove it?

Comment: This is true of _every_ orthonormal basis in $\mathbb R^3$ (up to a minus sign, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [circular shift property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Properties) of cross product we get:
$$\langle T \times B,N \rangle=\langle N \times T,B \rangle=-\langle T \times N,B \rangle=-1$$